# how to show only current date data in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm building a website in ASP.NET and I'd like to show only current date data in a GridView.

This is my C# code.

```
public void GridBind()
{

    SqlCommand cmd_std = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM  StudentInfo WHERE GRNo = '" + GR_No + "' AND  school_id = '" + a + "' ", dbcon);
    SqlDataAdapter sda_std = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd_std);
    DataSet ds_std = new DataSet();
    sda_std.Fill(ds_std);


    if (ddlSubject.SelectedItem.Text == "All")
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from HomeWork where Date >= '" + txtdate.Text + "'  AND school_id='" + a + "' AND Standard='" + ds_std.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CurrentStd"].ToString() + "'", dbcon);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        gvhw.DataSource = ds;
        gvhw.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from HomeWork where Date >= '" + txtdate.Text + "'  AND Subject = '"+ddlSubject.SelectedItem.Text+"'  AND school_id='" + a + "' AND Standard='" + ds_std.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CurrentStd"].ToString() + "'", dbcon);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        gvhw.DataSource = ds;
        gvhw.DataBind();
    }
}
```

I need to display the current date inserted data show in GridView by default, i.e., if we bind the Grid on the page load then all data show in which I need to the same process but only show the current date data.

Comment: Don't you adHoc query and also please provide some sample data and expected output

Comment: Show the sample data from the underlying table and selected date

Comment: public void GridBind()
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from HomeWork where Date >= '" + txtdate.Text + "'  AND school_id='" + a + "' AND Standard='" + ds_std.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CurrentStd"].ToString() + "'", dbcon);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        gvhw.DataSource = ds;
        gvhw.DataBind();
    }

Comment: So you want today's date record from this `HomeWork` table?

Comment: @ Can you provide sample data from `HomeWork` table?

Comment: -> Question 1) In which format you have stored the date column value? 2) In what condition you need that default today's record?

Comment: date formet (dd/MM/yyyy)

Comment: condition only show the parents today homework in font when he search to date show that data

Comment: can you help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not clear so I made some assumptions:

Use below code which will load the current date's record *(When the actual page load)*

```
string TDate = string.Empty;

if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtdate.Text))
{
   TDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
}
else
{
   TDate = txtdate.Text;
}

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from HomeWork where Date = '" + TDate  + "'  AND school_id='" + a + "' AND Standard='" + ds_std.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CurrentStd"].ToString() + "'", dbcon);
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
sda.Fill(ds);
gvhw.DataSource = ds;
gvhw.DataBind();
```

EDIT:

```
string NewDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); 

public void GridBind() 
{ 
  dbcon.Open();  
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Id,FORMAT(Date,'dd/MM/yyyy') AS Date,Subject,Disc from NoticeBoard where school_id='" + a + "' and FORMAT(Date,'dd/MM/yyyy')= '" + NewDate + "' , dbcon); 

  SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd); 
  DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
  sda.Fill(ds); 
  gvTeacher.DataSource = ds; 
  gvTeacher.DataBind(); 
  dbcon.Close(); 
}
```

Comment: में अपने प्रोजेक्ट में जे डाटा आज की डेट का डाटा डाला गया ह वो पेज लोड पर शो KARANA CAHTI HU हो और परेसन्ट्स क सर्च पर जिस डेट का डाटा VO SEARCH KARE किया वो  SHOW HO

Comment: @MeghaChoubisa Yes that understand! Will update the answer

Comment: public void GridBind()
    {

        dbcon.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Id,FORMAT(Date,'yyyy/MM/dd')AS Date,Subject,Disc from NoticeBoard where school_id='" + a + "'", dbcon);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        gvTeacher.DataSource = ds;
        gvTeacher.DataBind();
        dbcon.Close();
    }

Comment: in this gridview hwo do same think

Comment: Show the tried code or Can you share your screen via AnyDesk??

Comment: share the code in this page please visit and i'm traning pried so not allow any disk

Comment: @MeghaChoubisa You need a where a condition for the date

Comment: public void GridBind()
    {

        dbcon.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Id,FORMAT(Date,'dd/MM/yyyy')AS Date,Subject,Disc from NoticeBoard where school_id='" + a + "'", dbcon);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        gvTeacher.DataSource = ds;
        gvTeacher.DataBind();
        dbcon.Close();
    }

Comment: @MeghaChoubisa Unable to understand but check the edit section and try

Comment: @MeghaChoubisa Then I can't help further without watching your code

Comment: Via email? or it will take max 10 mins to solve the issue try with anydesk will check

Comment: send your mail id

Comment: @MeghaChoubisa `prashantpimpale93@gmail.com`

Comment: @MeghaChoubisa Ok will checlk

Answer (score 0):

I dont quite understand what you asked. Could you provide some expected output please? But if you just wanna to show the current date :

```
DateTime tudey = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: I need to my report to only show the current date record in gridview asp.net c#

Comment: Could you please show some expected output? Edit your question, and give some expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void GridBind()
{

    dbcon.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Id,FORMAT(Date,'yyyy/MM/dd')AS Date,Subject,Disc from NoticeBoard where school_id='" + a + "'", dbcon);
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    sda.Fill(ds);
    gvTeacher.DataSource = ds;
    gvTeacher.DataBind();
    dbcon.Close();
}
```

Comment: hwo in this grid view do same think page load show current date data

Comment: same bady help me

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
    byte[] bytes;
    string fileName, contentType;
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select Name, Data, ContentType from tblFiles1 where Id=@Id ";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                sdr.Read();
                bytes = (byte[])sdr["Data"];
                contentType = sdr["ContentType"].ToString();
                fileName = sdr["Name"].ToString();
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = contentType;
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();


}
```

asp.net page code

'>

Comment: i need to downlode file in gridview using link button but it's not working